# How to update a jar that used on another project

Tags: maven, jar

I have two project.First project's name is studentApp, second one is coursesApp. I have imported two project on eclipse.First project(studentApp) uses courseApp jar as maven dependency.

I implemented a feature on studentApp project but this feature uses coursesApp project's service classes. Therefore, I had to change service classes on coursesApp project. Right now , my student project does not see service classes because jar is 1.0.I used `mvn clean install` commond on second project and created a new jar 1.0.1.

Now, I changed my pom.xml on first project to change version.I made 1.0.1 I used 
 `mvn clean install`but there is no jar.How can I do now? I think jar is on company repo.Do i have to add a new jar to company repo everytime to make changes?

Comment: It is difficult to follow you. If a dependency cannot be found, try to run Maven with the `-U` parameter

Comment: I created courseApp jar then I looked at maven repo folder I saw new version has been added.After that I compiled my studentApp project now I can see the courseApp new version jar in maven dependencies section on Elipse.

Comment: So the issue is solved? Or is this a question?

Comment: Yeah It is working now.